# Data set 'FA' not found in the drc package

Tags: r

I've been reading the [drc paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v12/i05/paper) and on page six, it has the following commands:

```
> library(drc)    
> data(FA)
```

However, I get the following error

```
In data(FA): data set 'FA' not found
```

Where can I get the `FA` data set?

Comment: What instructions/tutorial are you following?

Comment: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v12/i05/paper   (page 6)

Comment: After some research and actually applying the methods above, it seems in the newest version the dataset is called `ryegrass`. Also, the `multidrc` function in that paper is also called `drm` now. So far, this much.

To be honest I am a bit disappointed by the lack of documentation regarding the changes in R, compared to Matlab, Python and others. I have to search for hours to see which function is called what now.

Comment: Explaining my down-vote: This is a rather ridiculous set of complaints. When you follow the link at the end of that 6 year-old paper, you get to an up-to-date website with examples and links to the current version of the package.

Comment: Dwin, thanks for explaining your reason, but which link are you  referring to? The bioassay site: http://www.bioassay.dk/, quite old. drc package version: Yes, but does not tell you what was before. I code for open source projects for many years, and I don't find breaking backward compatibility without proper documentation _very pleasing_.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments in @Jack's answer, you can retrieve the `FA` dataset from the old package version, **but** you can still use the latest version of the package.

1. Download [version 0.8-2](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/drc/drc_0.8-2.tar.gz) of the drc package from the [archive web-page](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/drc/);
2. Unzip the package and go to the directory `data`;
3. Copy the file `FA.rda` to somewhere sensible;
4. Now use the following command: `load("FA.rda")`
5. This gives the data set on page 6 of the paper, i.e.

   ```
   R> FA[1:5,]
     MEANLR MM
   1  7.580  0
   2  8.000  0
   3  8.329  0
   4  7.250  0
   5  7.375  0
   ```

Comment: I was wondering if you could load the .rda files directly... Now I know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A preliminary search of [the documentation for the drc library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/drc/drc.pdf) reveals no data set called `FA`.  My advice would be to contact the authors of the paper to see if they can provide you with the data set.

Comment: You are right, in the sense that the **new version** does not have it. I looked back and it seems in previous version they had it: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/drc/  (**version 0.9**). Can I load that dataset somehow, and go on with the tutorial?

Comment: In that case, yes, you can uninstall the current version (using a bizarre and archaic-looking command... https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-January/223512.html  Oh, R, how I loathe you sometimes...), manually download and install the old version, and then you should be able to access the data set.

Comment: @JackManey what is bizarre or archaic about `remove.packages` as the inverse for `install.packages`?

Comment: I would just download new and old source, stick the FA dataset into the new version and compile. :P

Comment: Ah, so there is a `remove.packages`!  Cool.  No, what I thought looked archaic was `R CMD REMOVE <package name>` (invoked from the terminal).